# Идея программы в генерации 10 кружков. Не работает

Tags: javascript

css

```
.circle1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FCCE00;
  animation: width 3s infinite;
  }

@keyframes width {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
      }
  50% {
    transform: scale(100, 100);
     }
}
```

JS

```
function circle () {
var left = Math.random()*200;
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
var circle = document.createElement("div");
circle.class = "circle1";
document.body.appendChild(circle);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`circle.classList.add("circle1");`

```js
function circle() {
  var left = Math.random() * 200;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var circle = document.createElement("div");
    circle.classList.add("circle1");
    document.body.appendChild(circle);
  }
}

circle();
```

```css
.circle1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FCCE00;
  animation: width 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes width {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(100, 100);
  }
}
```